# JavaScript clock reloads to its own page?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a clock to my website with JavaScript, but I have a problem. The HTML page with my script in it will load and display everything in HTML, but about 1 second later will reload and only display the output of the JavaScript (only display the clock).

Here is my code:

```
window.onload = setInterval(clock, 1000);
var time = document.getElementById('TIME');

function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var localtime = date.toString();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  document.open("text/html", "replace");
  document.write("Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}
```

It would go from this: Displays everything in HTML file

To displaying JUST THIS: "Time: 15:16:56"

I have no idea what I did wrong and it would be awesome if I can get some help. (I am just learning how to use JavaScript)

Comment: `document.write` (well, `document.open`) deletes the existing page. If you’re working off of any book or tutorial that uses it, you should probably get a newer one.

Comment: remove last 2 lines and use this instead `time.innerHTML = "Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    window.onload = setInterval(clock, 1000);
    var time = document.getElementById('TIME');
    function clock() {
      var date = new Date();
      var localtime = date.toString();
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var seconds = date.getSeconds();
      time.innerHTML = "Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
```

```html
<div id="TIME"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried but but it no longer displays the time.

Comment: here is a codepen [js clock](https://codepen.io/akbarali812/pen/qBEXgLw)

Comment: ```time.textContent =```  is preffered in this scenario (https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `document.open(...)`. That reloads the page.

You should just do this:

```
time.innerHTML = "Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

instead of

```
document.open("text/html", "replace");
document.write("Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

UPDATE:

I just saw I made a typo. This code works (on codepen):

```js
window.onload = setInterval(clock, 1000);
var time = document.getElementById('TIME');

function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var localtime = date.toString();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  time.innerHTML = "Time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}
```

```html
<div id="TIME"></div>
```

Comment: I have tried but but it no longer displays the time.